# How can I list a string in a ListBox C#?

Tags: c#, string, listbox, streamreader

```
string myString = "";
string FilePath = "";

if (txtFilePath.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Please Enter Valid Path Name!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}

FilePath = txtFilePath.Text;

try
{
    StreamReader myInputFile;
    myInputFile = File.OpenText(FilePath);
    myString = "";

    while (myInputFile.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        //read a line of data from the file
       myString = myString + myInputFile.ReadLine();
       myString = myString + "\r\n";
    }

    myInputFile.Close();
    listBox1.Items.Add(myString);

}
catch (Exception myException)
{
    MessageBox.Show(myException.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}
```

My problem is the line where it says `myString = myString + "\r\n";`.
That's supposed to make my text that I'm pulling from my file have multiple lines, but when I run the program, there isn't any returned lines.

Also I tried using a label instead of a `ListBox`, but I need it to be a `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add each item to listbox rather than using \r\n.

```
try
    {
        StreamReader myInputFile;
        myInputFile = File.OpenText(FilePath);
        myString = "";

        while (myInputFile.EndOfStream == false)
        {
           myString = "";
            //read a line of data from the file
           myString = myString + myInputFile.ReadLine();
           listBox1.Items.Add(myString);
        }

        myInputFile.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you'd add each line to a `ListBox`. You're concatenating them all into one huge string with new lines in it.

Add each string one at a time like this instead:

```
while (!myInputFile.EndOfStream)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(myInputFile.ReadLine());
}
```

If the file isn't too large, you can get rid of nearly all of that, and replace it with this:

```
var file = File.ReadLines(FilePath);

listBox1.Items.AddRange(file.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multi-line text in a list box. I think that you want to add each line as a separate item. Also it is recommended to use `using` around your `StreamReader` to ensure that your resources are released properly. Try this:

```
try
{
    using(StreamReader myInputFile = File.OpenText(FilePath)){
        while (myInputFile.EndOfStream == false){
           //read a line of data from the file and add it to the list
           listBox1.Items.Add(myInputFile.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I did not need to close the `StreamReader`, because `using` will do that automatically for me. Alternatively, if you don't use `using`, you will have to add `finally` to your `try...catch` and dispose your `StreamReader` there like this:

```
finally{
    if(myInputFile != null)
        myInputFile .Dispose();
}
```